# Result Set manipulation with search-api in Marklogic

Tags: marklogic

I am working with `search-api` and wanted to know how to manipulate the search result on the fly? I need something like this:

I need to sort my result set on the basis of some criteria and if the value of the criteria is null then I should apply some arbitrary integer value so that I dont get the `xdmp:cast` exception.

Please help.

Regards
Amit

Comment: You can add sort constraints to the search options, and specify sort flags as part of the search string. But it would help if you could share some code..

Comment: Can you also elaborate on when and where you get the xdmp:cast exception?

Answer (score 1):

Each re-sort will require a fresh API call - `search:search` or `search:resolve`. You can set the search options appropriately for the sort key.

Fixing an `XDMP-CAST` exception requires a fix for the underlying datatype problem. What is the complete error message?

*EDIT*: As written, you could use something like this to handle non-integer values.

```
for $each in $x/ArticleSequenceNumber
order by
  if ($each castable as xs:integer) then xs:integer($each)
  else 0
return $each
```

But the search API does not handle that kind of thing. The search API is designed around large databases, where the search results are too large to fit in-memory all at once. So it expects to have range indexes available for sorting. Range indexes, in turn, depend on having clean input data.

The usual solution is to clean up your `ArticleSequenceNumber` element if you want to use it as a sort key with the search API. When the element would be empty, give it a dummy value or drop it from the XML entirely.

However, http://markmail.org/message/53pn6xioluwxdx4o might help. The idea here is to treat the values as strings instead of numbers, but sort them using a numeric collation.

```
for $each in $x/ArticleSequenceNumber
order by $each collation "http://marklogic.com/collation//MO"
return $each
```

You should be able to specify that same collation in your search constraint. The corresponding range index will be a string index with that same collation.

Comment: xquery version '1.0-ml';
let $x := <root>
<ArticleSequenceNumber/>
<ArticleSequenceNumber>1</ArticleSequenceNumber>
<ArticleSequenceNumber>5</ArticleSequenceNumber>
<ArticleSequenceNumber>10</ArticleSequenceNumber>
<ArticleSequenceNumber>63</ArticleSequenceNumber>
<ArticleSequenceNumber>54</ArticleSequenceNumber>
<ArticleSequenceNumber>19</ArticleSequenceNumber>
<ArticleSequenceNumber>21</ArticleSequenceNumber>
<ArticleSequenceNumber>29</ArticleSequenceNumber>
<ArticleSequenceNumber>11</ArticleSequenceNumber>
</root>
for $each in $x/ArticleSequenceNumber
order by xs:integer($each)
return $each

Answer (score 0):

```
xquery version '1.0-ml';
let $x := <root>
<ArticleSequenceNumber/>
<ArticleSequenceNumber>1</ArticleSequenceNumber>
<ArticleSequenceNumber>5</ArticleSequenceNumber>
<ArticleSequenceNumber>10</ArticleSequenceNumber>
<ArticleSequenceNumber>63</ArticleSequenceNumber>
<ArticleSequenceNumber>54</ArticleSequenceNumber>
<ArticleSequenceNumber>19</ArticleSequenceNumber>
<ArticleSequenceNumber>21</ArticleSequenceNumber>
<ArticleSequenceNumber>29</ArticleSequenceNumber>
<ArticleSequenceNumber>11</ArticleSequenceNumber>
</root>
for $each in $x/ArticleSequenceNumber
order by xs:integer($each)
return $each
```

Comment: this is the sample call, i want to handle the null values, it should come at the bottom of the result, and i want it to sort using the seacrh-api, please help.

Answer (score 0):

try using empty least (http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery/#id-orderby-return). That should make it so your null values show up last.

```
for $each in $x/ArticleSequenceNumber
stable order by xs:integer($each) empty least
return $each
```

if you put a ranged index on ArticleSequenceNumber and do the sorting in the right place you'll get the sorting coming off of the indexs.